# Why do I get 404 errors when running 'apt-get update'?

Tags: apt, updates

I am not able to update. I also have tried `update-manager`. It gives the the error message: *Failed to download repository information, check your Internet connection*.

```
praveen@praveen-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg                                                          
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg [933 B]                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg                                                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release.gpg                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                                 
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com raring Release [5,919 B]                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring Release                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                                                                                         
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Sources [2,693 B]                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources                                                                                  
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages [3,641 B]                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources                                                                                     
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages [4,792 B]                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources                                                                       
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg [316 B]                                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg [316 B]                                                                                            
Get:8 http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources [5,215 B]                                                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner amd64 Packages                                                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages                                                                                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Get:9 http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Sources [2,693 B]                                                                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner amd64 Packages                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner i386 Packages                                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en                                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                       
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [1,659 B]                                                                                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en                                                                                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources                                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources                                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                               
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [743 B]                                                                                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages                                                                                      
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [9,222 B]                                                                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_IN                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en                                                                                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                                                                                       
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [11.5 kB]                                                                                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_IN                                                                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                                                                                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en_IN                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                               
Ign http://archive.canonical.com raring/partner Translation-en                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources                                                                                          
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [657 B]                                                                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources                                                                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources                                                                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages                                                                                   
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources [603 B]                                                                                          
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en                                                                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                                                                              
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                                                                                      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages                                                                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages                                                                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en                                                                                    
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                              
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en           
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en             
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                  
Hit https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN                                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en                           
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources            
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages     
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages                      
  404  Not Found
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Fetched 50.9 kB in 1min 10s (722 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7B1AB59047B4D1C4
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'extras.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System error)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/guadalinex-members/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/guadalinex-members/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/guadalinex-members/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please mention your Ubuntu version which you are trying to update. From your error message, it seems that you have used a lot of 3rd party repository. Open synaptic->Settings->Repository->Other Softwar (tab) and then Uncheck all except first two check boxes. Then Reload Synaptic. Then try again.

Answer (score 2):

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/guadalinex-members/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

That error means that you are using a PPA that does not offer Raring packages.

The PPA is "[PPA for Guadalinex Members](https://launchpad.net/~guadalinex-members/+archive/ppa)
". To remove it, use [ppa-purge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html):

```
ppa-purge ppa:guadalinex-members/ppa
```

Comment: You may [run into trouble](http://askubuntu.com/a/344102/1859) when using ppa-purge to remove a PPA that has no available packages.