# Can't Purge X Updates PPA Because / is Treated as a Space?

Tags: ppa, input, purge

**sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates**

I've tried running that command... several times. Copy/pasted it, manually typed it, tried it in XTerm and Terminal, to no avail. The output is always:

**Could not find package list for PPA: ubuntu-x-swat x-updates**

There is no / in that output, which leads me to believe it's processing the / as a space and trying to find a PPA named exactly that.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try quoting (ie `sudo ppa-purge "ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates"`) the PPA name?

Comment: Quoting the PPA name doesn't help either; the same /-less output is posted.

Comment: Does this happen with other PPAs or just the x updates PPA?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's just a misleading error message. A quick [glance at the source](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ppa-purge/ppa-purge/ubuntu/view/head:/ppa-purge?start_revid=58#L120) reveals that it's printing a space where we'd normally type a slash:

```
warn "Could not find package list for PPA: $PPAOWNER $PPANAME"
```

So why couldn't it find the package list?

I believe that part of the message is also misleading. You'll likely find that there are, in fact, valid package lists for the PPA in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`:

```
$ ls /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_*_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-amd64_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-i386_Packages
```

The thing that's throwing off ppa-purge is that they're *empty*:

```
$ file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_*_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-amd64_Packages: empty
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ubuntu-x-swat_x-updates_ubuntu_dists_raring_main_binary-i386_Packages:  empty
```

It assumes that a repository will always contain packages, and that assumption doesn't hold true for ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates, which at the moment [doesn't have any packages for Raring](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates).

If you'd like to remove the PPA, you should be able to [use apt-add-repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/173199/1859) to remove it from the software sources.

It would also be courteous to let the developers of ppa-purge know about this exception so they can make it respond more helpfully in the future. You can [open a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#Non-crash_hardware_and_desktop_application_bugs) by running `ubuntu-bug ppa-purge`.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove Xorg Edgers ppa. Simply run

```
ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```